# Me da un error al importar el paquete donde esta la clase.java

Tags: java, jsp

[image: Código JSP]
LLevo dias en esto ya que uso los metodos dentro del archivo JSP y funcionan perfectamente pero a la hora de importalos de un archivo java me ocasiona un error q no he podido arreglar
Codigo Java

```
public class wtfmetodo {
    private static double resultado;
    public static double metodoSuma(int num1,int num2) {
        return resultado=num1+num2;
    }
    public static double metodoResta(int num1,int num2) {
        return resultado=num1-num2;
    }
    public static double metodoMultiplicacion(int num1,int num2) {
        return resultado=num1*num2;
    }
    public static double metodoDivision(int num1,int num2) {
        return resultado=num1/num2;
    }
}
```

Error

```
Ha tenido lugar un error en la línea: [10] en el archivo jsp: [/wtf1.jsp]
wtfmetodo cannot be resolved
7: <body>
8: <%
9: // Realiza la suma de dos numeros usando el metodo metodoSuma de la clase wtfmetodo
10: double resultadoSuma = wtfmetodo.metodoSuma(5, 7);
11: %>
12: 
13: El resultado de la suma de 5 y 7 es: <%= resultadoSuma %>
```

Este es el error al compilar